# Can anyone "predate" a comment or answer?

Tags: discussion

It may be my imagination but I think I see some comments or answers appearing after I write something although at the time I don't recall seeing them. I am judging this by the post time reported. Of course, it may be my memory showing my age! ;-) Or, is it possibly a bug? Or, is it due to time zone differences? Just curious.

Comment: Does this happen while you are writing an answer? I think (not sure though!) that other answers get a little expander-looking notification, and then when you post they load fully, which might cause that impression. The notifications are easy to miss because they are smaller and show up on top of the input box.

Comment: It can rarely happen that a moderator undeletes a comment or converts an answer to a comment, which then seem to appear out of nowhere. But I assume that this is not what you are talking about.

Comment: It should be obvious that I cannot provide an example, but I do recall providing an answer to a question with one comment only, later on discovering a comment talking to my point that was posted an hour or more before. As I said, it may very well be my memory is faulty, but I noticed this more than once and the question is one of curiosity questions about the mechanism of the forum than anything else. By the way, I never access the site from a mobile device but a laptop or a desktop. Judging by what I hear, it is a difficult question to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it does happen (happens a lot to me when i answer on my phone actually), there are several reasons for this.

1. It can happen that you were writing a comment/answer simultaneously. Normally you get a notification of updates.

   But it can also happen if you have invalidated your javascript by going back to the page of using it trough a very slow connection. Then what can happen is you see yours coming online first and then upon refresh its no-longer the case. If you accidentally did the invalidation than it can take hours for you to notice.
2. The user may have deleted the answer, and that answer then becomes un-deleted. It will still get the original author time stamp stamp of when it was first posted seemingly appearing from thin air.
3. Moderator intervention

Comment: Thank you, I tried to address the answer and the comments above. I think this question will be tough to answer, but your point #2 may be close. I have no way of ascertaining to accept any answer.

Comment: @ACEkin No problem you have labeled this as disussion